# Creating tables with foreign keys

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I am creating tables where I have foreign keys. This is part of the statements. For some reason I cannot get it to work.

What am i doing wrong?

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor (

NPI  NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
LNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PHONE  NUMBER  NOT NULL, 
ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
CITY  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL );



CREATE TABLE Patient (

SSN NUMBER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL, 
INSURANCE_POLICY_ID NUMBER NOT NULL, 
LNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FNAME VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
DOB DATE NOT NULL,
PHONE NUMBER NOT NULL,
ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CITY VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (INSURANCE_POLICY_ID) REFERENCES INSURANCE (INSURANCE_POLICY_ID));
```

Comment: `Number` is not a valid data type for sql server you should use `INT`

Comment: You should see some errors when executing these queries. Please, use `VARCHAR(255)` for all name type fields unless you have a very compelling reason. 20 characters for a name is way, way too short and it's especially troubling for addresses.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: When posting questions like this, you need to give us the error message you are getting so that we know what is going on. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have tagged your question with `SQL Server` and `MySql` both, in both of these RDBMS there is no data type called `Number` but there is a data type to store numbers it is called `INT` or `INTEGER`.

Therefore your table definitions should be as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE Doctor (
NPI     INT         NOT NULL    PRIMARY KEY ,
LNAME   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FNAME   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
PHONE   INT         NOT NULL,  --<-- should be a varchar since most phone numbers have a leading zero
ADDRESS VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CITY    VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL );



CREATE TABLE Patient (
SSN                 INT         NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, 
INSURANCE_POLICY_ID INT         NOT NULL, 
LNAME               VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FNAME               VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, 
DOB                 DATE        NOT NULL,
PHONE               INT         NOT NULL,
ADDRESS             VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
CITY                VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (INSURANCE_POLICY_ID) 
 REFERENCES INSURANCE (INSURANCE_POLICY_ID));
```